# Endpoint request timed out when starting AWS ECS task from Lambda

Tags: python, boto3, amazon-ecs

I am trying to run an ECS task from Lambda Api gateway. But frequently getting Endpoint request timed out. I have changed the default Labmda timeout to 5 min. But still getting timeout exception sometimes. **Is there any way to run the ECS task through Lambda without getting timeout ?**

[image]

Here is the core python code from Lambda to run an ECS task

```
ecs = boto3.client(
    'ecs',
    region_name=config.AWS_REGION,
    aws_access_key_id=config.AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID,
    aws_secret_access_key=config.AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY
)

request_id = str(uuid.uuid1())

ecs.run_task(
    cluster='test-cluster',
    taskDefinition='test-task',
    startedBy=request_id,
    launchType='FARGATE',
    overrides={
        'containerOverrides': [
            {
                'name': 'test-container',
                'environment': [
                    {
                        'name': 'request_id',
                        'value': request_id
                    }
                ]
            }
        ]
    },
    networkConfiguration={
        'awsvpcConfiguration': {
            'securityGroups': [
                'sg-XXXXXXXX',
            ],
            'subnets': [
                'subnet-XXXXXXXX',
                'subnet-XXXXXXXX',
                'subnet-XXXXXXXX'
            ],
            'assignPublicIp': 'ENABLED'
        }
    }
)
```

Comment: where are you seeing the timeout, in lambda or API Gateway?

Comment: In API Gateway. I have logged the execution time and saw that most of the time spend on `ecs.run_task` method.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

AWS API Gateway has a hard timeout limit of 29 seconds. So regardless of the timeout limit of your lambda, the API Gateway will return a timeout if it doesn't get a response after 29 seconds.

Your lambda should carry on regardless though, this should be simple enough to verify in cloudwatch logs.

I'm not sure what you want API Gateway to return in this scenario, but it may be enough to have lambda begin the job and return a response to API gateway that the job has begun.

To do this I would  have API Gateway call a Lambda that invoked the Lambda running the ECS task. To make this asynch, the invocation from Lambda to Lambda would need to be an 'Event' invocation type.

Example:

```
import boto3
import json

def lambda_handler(event, context):
response = client.invoke(
    FunctionName='<ecs_lambda>',
    InvocationType='Event',
    Payload=json.dumps(event)
)
return { "result": "OK" }
```

Comment: I know it's 30 sec and I have changed this to 5 min. But still getting timeout sometimes. What i want is, Is there any way to run the ECS task through Lambda without getting timeout

Comment: @Ashraful Islam - The 29 second API Gateway limit, is a hard limit. You could not have raised this to 5 minutes. You may have changed the Lambda timeout to 5 minutes, but not the API Gateway.

Comment: thanks for the information. by the way is there any way to return the response to api gateway immediately but keep the process until finished in lambda ?

Comment: I've amended my answer to include an example